# Apex - passing a variable from one page to another

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a form on one page which prompts a user to enter their email address. When they click "next" I want Apex to redirect the user to a different page which shows them a report which selects the records from the users table where the email address matches the one that they entered.

E.g.

SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = (the email address that they entered on the previous page);

Can someone please explain the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have only in the last 5 seconds heard about 'Apex' Lol ... But I think I found what you need to do.

You need to define a 'Branch' which will allow you to POST to whichever page you need to.

Here's some documentation on 'Branches': http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32472_01/doc/appdev.300/b32469/pdf_report.htm#BABICIJG

Also this snipet may help:

> It's [The 'branch'] in the middle (page processing section) of the
>   development page at the bottom. The branch will be executed whenever a
>   post submission occurs but you can put conditions on the branch.

Which I found at: http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=8139

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this an unfortunately it has not worked.

Comment: Well, that's me out of ideas then ... But, just in case it helps, here's a picture of 2 cats hugging. http://richardwiseman.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/cats-hugging.jpg

Comment: Hahaha. Very touching.

Answer (score 0):

The "Next" button should not redirect but should submit. The value of the page item has to be pushed to the session state for it to be available in the (apex) session. On submit you can then define a branch which will take you to the page with your report. Your report can then reference the page item by using bind variable notation in the region source:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = :Px_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```